# TypeDoc: How to use typedoc-plugin-markdown & typedoc-plugin-zod so infered zod types look better on md?

Tags: plugins, markdown, documentation, zod, typedoc

I'd like to generate my TypeDoc files with the markdown plugin, and then use the zod plugin so the inferred types actually tell you something and not just

```js
z.infer<typeof AccountResponse>
```

But when I run

`typedoc --plugin typedoc-plugin-markdow`

and then

`typedoc --plugin typedoc-plugin-zod`

My markdown files turn html again, as it is typedocs default.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can pass `--plugin` multiple times

Comment: @Gerrit0 thanks for your reply, saw you created the zod plugin, thats nice!
I changed something with a zod abstraction I had and its working now.

Comment: @Gerrit0 may I ask something else?
I'm looking at the generated `Defined in` in the mds, which is great to have, but I notice that the link takes you to the `/blob/last-commit-hash/src/file.ts`, and I'd like to have it only when I push to main, and for it to be `/blob/main/src/file.ts`.
I'm adding a workflow to run the command only when pushing to main, do you know how can I do this? :)

Comment: found `--gitRevision main` :p